# Getting the psuedo element property of css work.. to change the property of first line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the css property of first line of a big sentence, I am experimenting with it by using color property, I have an html element

```
<span class="tripname_heaing">Where Hummus All Began: Jasdasdasddasdasdasdasdadasdasdasdasdsadsadasdasdordan &amp; Issdassasdsadsadsadrael</span>
```

and CSS property

```
.span.tripname_heaing:first-line {
color: red
}

span.tripname_heaing{
 color: blue
}

span.tripname_heaing {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 24pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But the psuedo element property is not working with the above syntax. I am adding a fiddle to show the demo. What could be wrong with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/X33pY/126/

And edit made to fiddle to show the feature
http://jsfiddle.net/X33pY/126/

Answer (score 3):

The `::first-line` pseudo element doesn't apply to inline-level elements; from [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-line):

> In CSS, the ::first-line pseudo-element can only have an effect when
>   attached to a block-like container such as a block box, inline-block,
>   table-caption, or table-cell.

You can instead use a `<p>` or change the display value of the `<span>` -  http://jsfiddle.net/X33pY/127/

Answer (score 0):

You had a lot of problems like `color: red`, it should be `color: red;`

You also had to add `display: block;` to the main container since it is a span tag, these are not block elements.

```
.tripnameHeaing {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 24pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
}

.tripnameHeaing:first-line {
  color: red;
}
```

[jsfiddle with answer](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/X33pY/134/)